# ¿Como agrego una fila clonando la información de otra?

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla y en las filas tengo dos botones ("nueva fila" y "eliminar"), lo que necesito es que al agregar una nueva fila se clone la información de la fila en la que se hizo clic.

La función está realizando la clonación dependiendo de lo que le indique ya sea con First o Last pero no se como hacer para que sea la fila actual.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nuevalinea").click(crearNuevaFila);

    function crearNuevaFila() {
        var filaclonada = $("#tablaresponsive").find("tbody tr:first").clone();
        filaclonada.click(crearNuevaFila)
        $("#tablaresponsive tbody").append(filaclonada);
    }

    $("#tablaresponsive").on('click', '.eliminalinea', function () {
        var numeroFilas = $("#tablaresponsive tr").length;
        if(numeroFilas>2){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });

});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no lo haces igual que hiciste la eliminacion?

Comment: si bueno lo que pasa es que apenas estoy incursionando en jquery y demás entonces aún me pierdo mucho, si me puedes ayudar o explicar un poco te lo agradecería!!

Answer (score 3):

Así como usaste el método `closest()` para capturar el padre `tr` del botón al que le diste clic entonces usa lo mismo para capturar otra vez a dicho `tr` solo que esta vez en lugar de remover vas a clonar:

```
$(this).closest("tr").clone();
```

Ahora te recomiendo que si estas usando los selectores de **jQuery** para ejecutar los eventos lo hagas de principio a fin para mantener la misma estructura en cuanto a la lógica que estás usando.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#tablaresponsive").on('click', '.nuevalinea', function () {
      var filaclonada = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
      
      var valores_select = [];
      
      $.each($(this).closest("tr").find('select'), function(index, select){
         valores_select.push({
            select: $(select).attr('id'),
            valor: $(select).val()
         });
      });
      
      $("#tablaresponsive tbody").append(filaclonada);
      
      $.each(valores_select, function(index, dato){
        $(filaclonada).find('#' + dato.select).val(dato.valor);
      })
      
  });

  $("#tablaresponsive").on('click', '.eliminalinea', function () {
      var numeroFilas = $("#tablaresponsive tr").length;
      if(numeroFilas>2){
          $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablaresponsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</th>
      <th>Item 2</th>
      <th>Item 3</th>
      <th>Opciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="primero">
          <option value="">Seleccione</option>
          <option value="Valor 1">Valor 1</option>
          <option value="Valor 2">Valor 2</option>
          <option value="Valor 3">Valor 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="segundo">
          <option value="">Seleccione</option>
          <option value="Valor 1">Valor 1</option>
          <option value="Valor 2">Valor 2</option>
          <option value="Valor 3">Valor 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td>
        <button class="nuevalinea">Nueva línea</button>
        <button class="eliminalinea">Eliminar línea</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EXPLICACIÓN DE LA EDICIÓN:**

Una vez visto el problema del sistema al tener 2 o más `select` se me ocurrió guardar los valores en un `array` de objetos para luego recorrerlo y asignar dichos valores a sus `select` clonados correspondientes.

Comment: Esta bien y me funciona como lo necesito, pero vi algo y es que cuando se tienen dos select dentro de la tabla al clonar una fila el sistema no presenta bien el segundo select.

Comment: @user88036 Eso es por que debes de capturar el valor de cada select independiente y añadirlo al select clonado correspondiente, si lo haces tal cual como yo lo planteé no te va a funcionar, si quieres te cambio el ejemplo a 2 select ya tu me dirás

Comment: ummm me serviría mucho es para un trabajo y ando colgada, me servirían de mucha ayuda o me puedes explicar el código que me enviaste ya yo miro como resuelvo ese pedacito, muchas gracias

Comment: @user88036 te he hecho una edición a la respuesta, espero que ya todo quede mas claro de igual forma no dudes en preguntar si no me hice entender en algo